# If $P(x) = x^3-kx^2+2kx-8$, prove that the values of k for which P(x) has real roots are $K\le-2$ or $K\ge6$.

Tags: polynomials

$(x-a)$ is a factor of the polynomial $P(x)$, where $a$ is an integer.
If $P(x) = x^3-kx^2+2kx-8$, prove that the values of k for which P(x) has real roots are $K\le-2$ or $K\ge6$.

I tried differentiating it and using the discriminant but I couldn't that prove $K\le-2$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since x=2 is a root, you can factor out $(x-2)$

Comment: I suppose the question should be "for which $P(x)$ has three real roots" or "for which $P(x)$ has only real roots", because $P(x)$ has at least one real root $(x=2)$ whatever the value of $k$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$P(x) = (x-2)(x^2+(2-k)x+4).$$

So, $P(x)$ always has a root $x=2$.

If you want $P(x)$ has three real roots, then $(2-k)^2-16 \geq 0$, ( $k\geq 6$ or $k \leq -2$).